# Email template System Configuration Value

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

Magento get Email template System Configuration Value

```
<customeremail>
    <label>Customer Email</label>
    <frontend_type>Select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <comment>Customer Email</comment>                   
</customeremail>
```

I called this way:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig ( 'mps_proxelle/enable/customeremail' );
```

But it prints 1 only. How to get Value in phtml ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it print email template id. Now you have to load email template with this id like :

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load(Mage::getStoreConfig('mps_proxelle/enable/customeremail'));
```

Comment: No it's not print anything